# Error: Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall application

Tags: installation, windows-8.1, visual-studio-2012

I'm running Windows 8.1 and wanted to install the visual studio 2012 ultimate (I ran it as administrator, if that helps). It finished installing correctly but when I'm trying to lunch the program I get this error message: "Cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall the application."

And so I did (reinstalling), but then I get another error message: eventlog is full. I have no clue what to do here.

I have enough disk space for the install for sure. I tried to empty the event log and reinstall but then I get the error: "cannot find one or more components. Please reinstall". then I tried reinstalling and I was back at square one (event log full).

If someone has a clue to what is happening please comment

Comment: Check to make sure you have sufficient disk space for the install.  Visual Studio typically takes a lot of space during the install.

Comment: [The first result from Google](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mandi/archive/2013/08/21/visual-studio-2012-quot-the-event-log-file-is-full-quot-error-message.aspx) tells you how to resolve the "event log is full" error.

Comment: Go look at your event log, it'll probably be filling up with the errors that will point out why VS is having troubles... Perhaps empty it and then try the install again, then look a the log for errors.